# Magento 2 : Simply want to change the text colour on my checkout page

Tags: checkout, css, magento2.2.2

Sorry for what is probably another daft question but after 2 hours of trying to work out how to make a simple change, I've admitted defeat! My **proceed to checkout** button is on a **white background** so people have **trouble spotting** it. I don't want much.

I just want to change the **background/text color**? Can I find where to do that?

[image]

Comment: You can add custom css file and your css!

Comment: share your development site here, I'll tell what need to be update and where?

Comment: Hi, Thanks so much for the reply. The website is at www.gorillaracking.co.uk